# Installing pglogical: Find postgres include folder, add all include folders to C_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, pg-logical

I am trying to install the pglogical extension in my postgres database, which I installed on my macOS with homebrew. I am following instructions provided on the GCP blog as I am preparing to migrate my database to CloudSQl with Database Migration Service.

I am struggling to complete the following step of [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/preparing-postgresql-migration-database-migration-service), and could use some advice:

> Find where Homebrew installed Postgres, find include folder, add all include folders to C_INCLUDE_PATH

My questions are:

- I found the include folder with `pg_config --includedir`
- But now, where is the pglogical `C_INCLUDE_PATH` variable? (I searched the pglogical repo and didn't find it) Or where do I create the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` variable?
- Am I to add all subdirectories of the include folder to the `C_INCLUDE_PATH` variable?

When I run `make` in the pglogical repo, I get the following:

```
sed 's/__PGLOGICAL_VERSION__/2.4.1/;s/__REQUIRES__//' /.../.../Documents/pglogical/pglogical.control.in > /.../.../Documents/pglogical/pglogical.control
```

Answer (score 1):

`pglogical` is a third party postgreSQL extension provided by [2ndQuadrant](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources-old/pglogical/) and is not part of PostgreSQL.  Some of it is written in C++, so must be compiled and built on the platform that it runs on.  While many prebuilt tools and packages are available for macos via `homebrew`, `pglogical` doesn't seem to be one -- it was my search for this that led me to your question.

Options are:

- build, install, and enable a version for macos from source code
- install one of the packaged linux versions in a Docker container alongside postgres
- run against a version on your cloud provider (I am using AWS, looks like you're on GCP)

Building and installing on macos is pretty straightforward.  In my case, I installed postgresql (14.1) using `homebrew`.  Once complete:

- clone the [pglogical extension from github](https://github.com/2ndQuadrant/pglogical)
- ensure that you have XCode and command-line tools installed -- run `brew doctor` if you're not sure
- follow instructions for "unix-like platforms" [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Building_and_Installing_PostgreSQL_Extension_Modules):

  - `make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1/bin/pg_config`
  - `make PG_CONFIG=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/14.1_1/bin/pg_config install`

Next, add the extension to `shared_preload_libraries` in postgres:

- `cd /usr/local/var/postgres`
- edit `postgresql.conf`

  - find the commented line `shared_preload_libraries`
  - add a line `shared_preload_libraries = 'pglogical';`
- restart postgres (with homebrew: `brew services restart postgresql`)

Finally, enable the extension in your local server:

- psql

  - `CREATE EXTENSION pglogical` which should respond with
  - `CREATE EXTENSION`

This all worked for me!  Hope your luck is as good.